# Single sign in for 2 apps

Tags: android, single-sign-on, autologin

Actually my question very similar to [Single Sign-On in Android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850691/single-sign-on-in-android-apps) but since it has no answers I am creating a new one in the hopes of finding an answer.

I have 2 apps under the same domain(com.example.appone and com.example.apptwo) that use the same sign up/sign in APIs but provide different functionalities. Generally in each app I store the session related information in their own SQLite DB.

What I want to do is I want to share this session related information between my apps such that if an user logs in one app then he/she doesn't have to log in again in the second one.

I tried googling but I could only find SSO logins provided by Google, Facebook and other 3rd party providers, which I don't want to use.

Kindly suggest guys.

Comment: You can use ContentProvider for that case and can Share the data of database.

Comment: @NigamPatro Yes I thought about it, but wouldn't that be a security risk?

Comment: Refer this link https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html and goto section **Using content providers** and check that out. It will be helpful to you I think

Comment: @NigamPatro thanks. It was helpful. I could've set `android:protectionLevel` to `signature` but unfortunately both of my apps are signed with different `keystore`.

Answer (score -1):

this is very simple you can use these two functions to save login status and login data

```js
 public static void saveLoginStatus(Context context, boolean isLoggedIn) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
        ed.putBoolean(PreferencesKeys.LOGIN_STATUS, isLoggedIn);
        ed.commit();
    }

   public static void saveUserData(Context context, UserDataClass userDataClass) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
        ed.putString(PreferencesKeys.USER_DATA, new Gson().toJson(userDataClass));
        ed.commit();
    }
```

than on the start of each app get The Login status if user is already login, automatically login him on the second app too

> **Note** you can get login information from getting UserData class you have saved.its all about logic you implement.
>   for security purpose you can implement inscription.

Comment: This won't allow me to read the `SharedPreferences` in other app. I'll have to set mode `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` but then any app can read it.

Comment: both database are structured same?

Comment: Yes, both of them are same.

Comment: ok than do't save full data but login status and some key value through which you can retrieve data from database in other app 

this way you will be saving useless data for other apps in SharedPreferences.

Comment: So, in other words I'll have to make a `ContentProvider`. That's what NigamPatro suggested above.

Comment: yeah but providing useless data so other app can't get anything of it